# SVG shadows do not repeat the element contour

Tags: html, css, svg, rust, yew

I am trying to render an SVG world map where I can select countries. I want to add a shadow effect for a particular country for the `onmouseenter` event. Everything works fine except that for some countries shadows do not follow the country border completely. Here is how it should work, the whole country is surrounded by a shadow:[image: Good example]

Here is what happens for some countries, you can see that shadow is absent for the southern border: [image: Bad example]

What do you think is the reason for this? I tried several SVGs and always the same problem.

I am using Rust Yew framework to build this, however, I think the problem is more related to SVG or CSS stuff which I don't really know well.
Here is my CSS:

```
.shadow {
    filter: drop-shadow( 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7));
    z-index: 999;
}
```

This is how I render the map:

```
impl Country {
  fn toggle_highlight(e: MouseEvent, enable: bool) {
    let style = if enable {
      "#fcecec"
    } else {
      "#ececec"
    };
    let class = if enable {
      "country shadow"
    } else {
      "country"
    };
    e.target()
      .and_then(|t| t.dyn_into::<SvgElement>().ok())
      .map(|el| {
        el.set_attribute("fill", style)
          .expect("Unable to set style attribute for the country path");
        el.set_attribute("class", class)
          .expect("Unable to set class attribute for the country path");
      });
  }

  fn render(&self) -> Html {
    let onmouseenter = Callback::from(|e: MouseEvent| Country::toggle_highlight(e, true));
    let onmouseleave = Callback::from(|e: MouseEvent| Country::toggle_highlight(e, false));
    html! {
      <path class="country" id={self.id.clone()} name={self.name.clone()} d={self.path.clone()} onmouseenter={onmouseenter} onmouseleave={onmouseleave}></path>
    }
  }
}

...

html! {
  <svg baseprofile="tiny" fill="#ececec" stroke="black" viewBox="0 0 1500 1500"
       width="100%" height="100%" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
       stroke-width=".2" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       style="border: 1px solid red">
    { for build_countries_list().iter().map(|c| c.render()) }
  </svg>
}
```

I am not sure it makes sense to post also SVG data here, please let me know if it is necessary.

Comment: but I set z-index for the `.shadow` element, isn't this enough?

Comment: I see. So what is the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other countries outlines are on top and obscure the shadow.

To reveal the shadow move the element so it's last in DOM order.